# Generating jasper report by using method call in grails

Tags: grails, jasper-reports, jasper-plugin

I know,By using `<g:Jasper>` tag I can generate report in grails but I want to save the report generated directly to a folder,mostly using method, iss any of you have any Idea regarding this

Answer (score 2):

Let's say your controller `con` and method `met` execute the jasper report export. And in `params` you pass some parameters. Let's say the parameters are `name, reportFile, 'date`.
Then you can get the report export by calling this link from any where:

```
http://yourDomain.com/con/met?name=myName&date=21-11-2012&reportFile=fileName
```

For example: I recently exported a jasper report using this link:

```
http://localhost:9096/WebSite/agent/agentTouchExport?_format=XLSX&_name=Export+to+xlsx&_file=AgentTouchReport&distributorWallet=&srWallet=&agentWallet=&businessRegionId=0&businessAreaId=0&businessTerritoryId=0&fromDate=2017-01-01&toDate=2017-02-03
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are asking to save jasper generated report to a file. This is easy. You can obtain report content (as byet array) from jasper. Then just save the content to a file. An example is given below-

```
JasperService jasperService;

def saveReport(GrailsParameterMap params, Locale locale, List<DataModel> models) {
    // Prepare data
    List searchReportSheet = new ArrayList();
    LinkedHashMap<String, Object> searchSheetMap;
    models.each {
        searchSheetMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
        searchSheetMap.put("key", it.keyValue);
        ...............
        ...............
        searchReportSheet.add(searchSheetMap);
    }

    // Call jasper for generate report
    def reportDef = jasperService.buildReportDefinition(params, locale, [data: searchReportSheet]);

    // Save to File
    def content = reportDef.contentStream.toByteArray();
    FileOutputStream fileOuputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileDest)
    fileOuputStream.write(content);
}
```